# JPA find by with multi conditions

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

here im trying to jpa to fetch the data from mysql db but im stucked with findby How to write findBy method for the below query using crudrepository spring data jpa?

```
select t.id, t.MSISDN, t.Param1, t.param2
  from BULK_REPOSITORY t
where t.Camp_Start_Date between Sysdate - 2 and sysdate
   and t.status = 0
   and t.camp_type = 1;
```

i have tried this but its does not work:

```
List<Bulk_repository> findByStatusInAndfindByCamp_typeIn(int status, int camp_type);
```

i have entity class like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BULK_REPOSITORY")
public class Bulk_repository {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "msisdn")
   private String msisdn;

   @Column(name = "camp_start_date")   
   private Date camp_start_date;

   @Column(name = "camp_end_date")
   private Date camp_end_date;

   @Column(name = "camp_type")
   private int camp_type;

   @Column(name = "camp_cd")
   private String camp_cd;

   @Column(name = "status")
   private int status;

   @Column(name = "process_date")
   private Date process_date;

   @Column(name = "entry_date")
   private Date entry_date;

   @Column(name = "entry_user")
   private String entry_user;

   @Column(name = "param1")
   private String param1;

   @Column(name = "param2")
   private String param2;

   @Column(name = "param3")
   private String param3;

   @Column(name = "param4")
   private String param4;

   @Column(name = "param5")
   private String param5;

   @Column(name = "error_desc")
   private String error_desc;
```

Comment: Why no pass the date range as a parameter to the method?

Comment: becuase it returns the below error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.accessingdatajpa.Bulk_repositoryRepository.findByStatusInAndfindByCamp_typeIn(int,int)! No property inAndfindByCamp found for type int! Traversed path: Bulk_repository.status.

Comment: The error is because you don't have any field named findByCamp. Should be AndCamp_typeIs or AndCamp_typeIn (when you want to pass an array )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below

```
 List<Bulk_repository>  findAllByStatusAndCamp_typeAndCamp_start_dateBetween(
int status, int camp_type,Date camp_start_dateStart, Date camp_start_dateEnd)
```

Wherever you want to call it

```
@Autowired
private Bulk_repository bulkRepository;


public List<Bulk_repository> getListRepositoryByConditions(){
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);

Date startDate = cal.getTime();

Date endDate = new Date();

return bulkRepository.findAllByStatusAndCamp_typeAndCamp_start_dateBetween(
0, 1,startDate, endDate);

}
```

Comment: how can i pass the data ? , i have tried this findAllByStatusAndCamp_typeAndCamp_start_dateBetween(0,1,2019-10-20,2019-10-22)

Comment: Start and end date should be object of date

Comment: sorry im i have no experiance with java or spring can u show me how ?

Comment: edited my answer to guide you, but you will have to put rest effort @yongshi

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you pass the date range as parameters to the method.

```
 List< Bulk_repository> findByStatusIsAndCamp_typeIsAndCamp_start_dateBetween(int status, int campType, Date start, Date end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Query` [from Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) with JPQL:

JPQL doesn't support periods. So you have to handle it yourself:

```java
@Query("SELECT t from Bulk_repository t " + 
    "WHERE t.camp_start_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND :currentDateMinus2 " + 
    "AND t.status = :status " + 
    "AND t.camp_type = :campType")
List<Bulk_repository> findByStatusInAndfindByCamp_typeIn(
    @Param("status") int status, 
    @Param("campType") int camp_type, 
    @Param("currentDateMinus2") Date currentDateMinus2);
```